# ajax prevent double posting on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone point out what I need in my code to stop it doubling up on data when you mouseenter on the hyperlink tag. I put a flag in there isLoading but it still continues to double up. I've probably done it wrong could someone have a look through my code and see whats wrong with it - see if you can prevent it from double posting on mouseenter. Please show me you're changes - Thanks from KDM.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.rating_display = function() {
        var _this = this;
        var id = $(_this).data('id');
        var position = $(this).parent().position();         
            var left = position.left - 15;  
            var top  = position.top + $(this).height() + 13;
        var isLoading = false;

        function clear_ratings() {
            $('.ratings-content').html(""); 
        }

        $(document).on('click', function(e) {
            var element = e.target;

            /*else if($(element).closest('.rating').length){
                $('.ratings-display').show();
            }*/

        });
        // here is where I'm having trouble with double posting
        $(this).on('mouseenter click', function(e) {
            if(isLoading == true) return false;

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST', 
                dataType:"html",
                data:{product_id:id},
                url:"../../webservices/get_rating.php",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    clear_ratings();
                    $('.ratings-display').show().css({'left':left + 'px', 'top':top + 'px'});
                    isLoading = true;   
                },
                success: function(data) {                                                                       
                    $('.ratings-content').append(data);                                             
                }, error:function(data, status, xhr) {
                    clear_ratings();
                    $('.ratings-content').html(data + "\r\n" + status + "\r\n" + xhr);  
                }
            });
        }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
            var target = e.relatedTarget;

            if($(target).closest('.ratings-display').length) {
                return false;   
            }else{
                $('.ratings-display').hide();
                clear_ratings();
                isLoading = false;
            }
        });

        $('.ratings-display').on('mouseleave',function (e) {            
            var target = e.relatedTarget;

            if($(target).closest('.rating').length) return false;

            if(!$(target).closest('.ratings-display').length) {
                $('.ratings-display').hide();
                clear_ratings();isLoading = false;  
            }


        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'mouseenter click'` means the action is performed once at mouseenter and again if you click.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `isLoading = true;` before the ajax call rather than in the `beforesend` function. And you also want to reset `isLoading = false` on ajax call completion rather than on mouseleave. Depending on whether you're doing it for keyboard navigation reasons or not, you could also stop listening to the click event entirely.

Comment: Thanks for you're input I do need the click event for tablet computers that's why it's there.

Comment: @kdm `mouseenter touchstart` would probably be the best events in that case